# Heroku deploy the telegram bot and got error h20

Tags: python, heroku, telegram-bot

Deployed the telegram bot on heroku. First I fixed a bunch of errors on library incompatibility, but then I got an H20 error and I don't even know how to approach it

[image]

Comment: I saw that you can also deploy bots to heroku

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: The H20 and H10 error says you are attemtping to access a website and you are not deploying a website. So these errors are expected.

Comment: and how can i solve the problem?

Comment: Either you build a website and deploy that. Or you stop attempt visiting a website that does not exist.

Comment: what is the difference between placing a bot and a site, I did it in the tutorial and there was no such problem

Comment: A website is build upon html, javascript and css. Google, Stackoverflow, Reddit, Twitter, etc. have websites you can visit from your web browser. A bot usually doesn't have a website (but it can - which you need to write the logic for). It's basically a script that runs in console interacting with third party APIs. The only way to see the bot is through console or through the action it has done by interacting with third party APIs. From the looks of it you are not developing a website so the error that no website is deployed is an expected error.

Comment: but i only want to deploy the bot. What does the site have to do with it. I'm not a fool and I write websites myself and this is my first time dealing with heroku

Comment: I explained to you what the `H20` error means. You tried accessing the website see the `GET` and `path="/"`. Those errors come from accessing the website. We are talking entirely in circles. Don't access the website when deploying the bot and you won't see the `H20` error. You may run into other problems but it's unrelated to the `H20` error. And for those problems you need to raise a new question. The question you have asked here is answered.

Comment: As far as I understand it needs to be changed heroku ps:scale web=1 on heroku ps:scale worker=1  and in procfile. But now have h14 error "No web processes running"

Comment: This again is an expected error. You are not deploying a web service so a web process shouldn't be running. Why are you attempting to visit the website? You shouldn't do that. Then you don't get those errors.

Comment: But bot doesn't work if i don't visit site. I have already tried to deploy in pythonanywhere but there is not enough space on numpy